# interrupt a function if it is running for more than a specified time

Tags: android

I have a function (written in c++ with Android NDK) to do some image processing. However, sometimes the function is stuck and my app freezes. To avoid this I tried the following:

```
processingDone = false;
thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
          angle = lineDetection(mat5.getNativeObjAddr()); // c++ function
          processingDone = true;
     }
});
thread.start();
long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 80;
while (endTime > System.currentTimeMillis() && !processingDone);
thread.interrupt();
thread = null;
```

Now, when the function get stuck, the app crashes instead of freezing. What am I doing wrong? (I am using Android Studio).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is there any way you can prevent the function from freezing in the first place? And have you thought about using asynchrony for this?

Comment: It's hard to find where the freeze comes from, since it happens only occasionally and when it happens, the phone is not connected to the computer so I cannot see where the function is stuck. I am not familiar with asynchronous programming, I would just like to know why my code is not working. Or do you think it is not possible to do it my way? Thanks for your reply.